# PHP why i cant run empty(FALSE) code?

Tags: php

i just wanted to make sure tha if you pass `FALSE` as an argument to an `empty()`, it will return `TRUE`:

```
var_dump(empty(FALSE));
```

But i cant.
Here is what i'm getting:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in Command line code on line 1
```

When i run this code in cmd:

```
C:\>php -r "echo empty(FALSE);";
```

I got this result:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in Command line code on line

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in Command line code on line 1
```

I thought i it will echo either `1` or `0`. but it didn't.
Any ideas?

Comment: `empty` expects a variable.

Comment: AH, GOOD OLD `T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`, I'VE MISSED YOU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`empty` only allows passing a named variable.

From http://php.net/empty

> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

Also from the same page,

> empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

`empty` expects a variable. You need to pass a variable like this:

```
$var = false;
if (empty($var))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Changelog

Version    Description
5.5.0      empty() now supports expressions, rather than only variables.
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php